# How to get index of a certain words in sublists?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, for-loop, list-comprehension

I declared `letters`, which one has more sublists, these sublists have between their elements at least the word "BUILD" or "SHOW", or even they can have both words between their elements.

What I want is to save in `indexes` the index of the first word found, for example `letters[0]` it just contain the word "BUILD" and its index would be `4`, then with `letters[1]` that contains both words, however the first word found is "SHOW", so I want to get that index which one would be `5`, then `letters[2]` which one contains both words too, however the important index is at the first word found, so the index to return would be `4`, and finally with `letters[3]` that contains just "SHOW" and its index would be `3`

So at the final when I print `indexes`, the result in console should be `[4, 5, 4, 3 ]`

I have written this:

```py
letters = [['letters1','a', 'c', 'b', 'BUILD'],
           ['letters2','F', 'P', 'Z', 'W', 'SHOW', 'BUILD'],
           ['letters3','R', 'X', 'N', 'BUILD', 'SHOW'],
           ['letters4','a', 'c','SHOW']]

indexes=[]
for letter in letters:
    for element in letter:
        if element=="BUILD" or element=="SHOW":
            indexes.append(letter.index(element))

print(indexes)
```

However the output in console is `[4, 5, 6, 4, 5, 3]` and what I understand my code is getting indexes for both words when it found and I don´t what that, I just want the index of the first word found.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
letters = [['letters1','a', 'c', 'b', 'BUILD'], ['letters2','F', 'P', 'Z', 'W', 'SHOW', 'BUILD'], ['letters3','R', 'X', 'N', 'BUILD', 'SHOW'], ['letters4','a', 'c','SHOW']]
indexes = []
for letter in letters:
   for i,let in enumerate(letter):
      if let == "BUILD" or let == "SHOW":
         indexes.append(i)
         break
```

You were almost there, just needed a `break`

Answer (score 2):

Use `break` to break out of the loop when condition met

```py
letters = [['letters1','a', 'c', 'b', 'BUILD'], ['letters2','F', 'P', 'Z', 'W', 'SHOW', 'BUILD'], ['letters3','R', 'X', 'N', 'BUILD', 'SHOW'], ['letters4','a', 'c','SHOW']]

indexes=[]
for letter in letters:
    for element in letter:
        if element=="BUILD" or element=="SHOW":
            indexes.append(letter.index(element))
            break # here

print(indexes)
```

```
[4, 5, 4, 3]
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
letters = [['letters1','a', 'c', 'b', 'BUILD'], ['letters2','F', 'P', 'Z', 'W', 'SHOW', 'BUILD'], ['letters3','R', 'X', 'N', 'BUILD', 'SHOW'], ['letters4','a', 'c','SHOW']]
indexes = []
for letter in letters:
   for i,let in enumerate(letter):
      if let == "BUILD" or let == "SHOW":
         indexes.append(i)
         break
```

Answer (score 1):

A simplified version of the code for your better understanding. The inner loop is iterated by the iterator across the length of the loop.

And then just use the 'break' / 'continue'.

```
    letters = [['letters1','a', 'c', 'b', 'BUILD'],
       ['letters2','F', 'P', 'Z', 'W', 'SHOW', 'BUILD'],
       ['letters3','R', 'X', 'N', 'BUILD', 'SHOW'],
       ['letters4','a', 'c','SHOW']]

    indexes=[]

    for letter in letters:
        for i in range(len(letter)):
            if letter[i]=="BUILD":
                indexes.append(i)
                break
            elif letter[i]=="SHOW":
                indexes.append(i)
                break
            else:
                continue

    print(indexes)
```